# Hibernate QueryException: could not resolve property

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

So I have these relations between these 3 tables
[image: check this pic]

And what I'm trying to do is to search (by `code` or `designation`) and get list of projects for a specific chief, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Project p JOIN ProjectHasChief phc ON (p.id = phc.idproject)
JOIN Chief c ON (c.id = phc.id_chief)
WHERE c.id = (myID)
AND (designation LIKE '%user_string%' OR code LIKE '%user_string%');
```

AND since I'm using hibernate I've used `Criteria`:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(ProjectHasChief.class);
            c.add(Restrictions.eq("chief", chief))
             .add(Restrictions.disjunction()
                    .add(Restrictions.like("project.designation", reg, MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
                    .add(Restrictions.like("project.code", reg, MatchMode.ANYWHERE)));
List<ProjectHasChief> list = (List<ProjectHasChief>)c.list();
```

But I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: project.designation of: smt.agm.entities.ProjectHasChief
```

**Project entity**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="projet")
public class Project {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition="serial")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name="designation")
    private String designation;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="project", orphanRemoval=true)
    @OrderBy(clause="id DESC")
    private List<ProjectHasChief> chiefs = new ArrayList<ProjectHasChief>();
}
```

**Chief entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="chief")
public class Chief {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition="serial")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

**ProjectHasChief entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="mapping_chantier_chef")
public class ProjectHasChief {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition="serial")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Project project;

    @ManyToOne
    private Chief chief;

    @Column(name="date_deb")
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name="date_fin")
    private Date endDate;
}
```

Whe hibernate don't know the property `designation` of `Project` entity ?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure all the mappings and joins actually work?

If so, you can try to declare an implicit alias for Project like so:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(ProjectHasChief.class);
        c.createAlias("project", "project") //THIS ONE
        c.add(Restrictions.eq("chief", chief))
        c.add(Restrictions.disjunction()
                .add(Restrictions.like("project.designation", reg, MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
                .add(Restrictions.like("project.code", reg, MatchMode.ANYWHERE)));

List<ProjectHasChief> list = (List<ProjectHasChief>)c.list();
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. But actually this is weird because I thought hibernate will know that because I'm using the same name in the entity and the query "project" !. But anyway thanx again for your time :)